# What is a life establishment fund?

Tags: college, trusts

I was talking to someone regarding saving for college education. I mentioned that I was putting money into a 529 account but wasn't happy with this. My kids my not decide to go to college and therefore the 529 would incur penalties.  They mentioned I should look at a 'Life Establishment Fund'  I haven't been able to find much information on this but it seems to be like a Trust ?

Anyone have more information ?

Comment: Guessing, but I bet that's the name of a product they are pushing, i.e. it's not a particular IRS designation. And I bet it's sold by a life insurance agent, who has kids of his own that he'd like you to put through college. There, I said it.

Comment: Google returns precisely 2 hits for the phrase "life establishment fund", both pointing at this question. I think you have the wrong name somehow.

Comment: It wasn't an agent of any kind. It was just a friend who made a comment. I don't have any more information other than that. Would a trust not accomplish what I am after?

Answer (score 1):

It's just money in an account somewhere with no tax shelter or string attached, to help maturing children (18-22ish) get a kick start in life whether they go to college or not.  Basically, the money can be used for anything (for you or them).  Or you can put it in a UGMA-type account where it's technically the child's funds and not yours (but check how college loans are calculated before dumping a bunch of money in those, I believe they are looked at differently, maybe as the first source of funds that gets tapped and could impact loan qualification).